# Visual Studio 2017 Google Test project organization + Test discovery failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest

I am having issues organzing my project and it's tests into a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 solution. My project is currently working as a .lib file and is working and being used by another solution on my computer.

I opened my project as a Solution, and then added a new project to the solution using 'Add Project..' and the Google Test Project prompt. I selected my project to test, and said I would consume google Test as a .lib and C++ runtime libraries would link dynamically.

I then compiled and Run All and discovery discovered the default started test that is automatically created. Great.

Then, I #include "../managers/ConfigManager.h" and try to Run All again and I get 'cannot open source file' for various header files used in my project .lib. Alright, so I add the appropriate include directories to my tests project properties.

'Run All' is now missing the libraries used by various components of my main project, so I add all the libraries to the Additional Dependencies and their directories to Additonal Dependency Directories in the tests project properties.

Trying to Run All again causes several things to happne.

1. I get the following output saying we can't find any tests.

   [3/31/2018 12:17:59 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:03.5029168) ==========

   [3/31/2018 12:18:03 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------

   [3/31/2018 12:18:04 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...

   [3/31/2018 12:18:08 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\TwinHits\Source\Repos\project\x64\Debug\tests.exe

   [3/31/2018 12:18:08 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...

   [3/31/2018 12:18:08 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:03.7586898

   [3/31/2018 12:18:08 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\TwinHits\Source\Repos\TwinHits\x64\Debug\tests.exe C:\Users\TwinHits\Source\Repos\project\x64\Debug\project.lib. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2. I'm getting this error after "Run test finished: 0 run".

   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
   System.InvalidOperationException: The following TestContainer was not found 'C:\Users\John Goben\Source\Repos\TIEngine\x64\Debug\Sample-Test1.exe'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerProvider. 
   d__62.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at

   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at 
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQuery.d__15.MoveNext()
3. main.cpp of my project runs, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Do you have any guidance for me on how to organize my tests and projects that makes tests run correctly, or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Test not finding any tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222112/google-test-not-finding-any-tests)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. Lib projects should not have main()'s. If someone can explain why this was messing up google tests' test discovery, I'd love to hear why.

Comment: Is it possible that your project's main() was executed instead of googletests' main()? But you are correct that libraries should not have main()s - if you are lucky your linker will complain that it has two definitions of main.obj with a main() function.

Answer (score 0):

VS googletest projects also add an option regarding main(). Use gtest_main() or use your own.
[image]