# Google Test not finding any tests

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest

So I'm working on creating my first unit tests.  I'm using Google Test, the version that is currently built into Visual Studio 2017.  This is an attempt at a proof of concept, so super simple.

I have a project in the solution for the test code: test.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1.cpp"

TEST(SumTest, FirstTest) {
  EXPECT_EQ(6, sum(2, 4));
}

TEST(SumTest, SecondTest) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

And I have a simple method to test in ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

int sum(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int x = sum(2, 4);
    printf("The answer is: %d \n", x);

}

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Everything compiles fine, but when I click 'Run All' from the Test Explorer menu, I get the following output:

```
[5/7/2018 4:17:42 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3666448
[5/7/2018 4:17:43 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:17:44 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:17:44 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[5/7/2018 4:17:44 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.9324761) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:20:39 PM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:20:40 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test discovery starting...
[5/7/2018 4:20:40 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:20:40 PM Informational] Test discovery completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3954411
[5/7/2018 4:20:40 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:20:40 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.8597435) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:20:47 PM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:20:48 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test discovery starting...
[5/7/2018 4:20:49 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:20:49 PM Informational] Test discovery completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3670275
[5/7/2018 4:20:49 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:20:49 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:20:49 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.873206) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:21:36 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:21:37 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3844604
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[5/7/2018 4:21:38 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:02.0203611) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:27:21 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:27:34 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.6936342
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[5/7/2018 4:27:35 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:14.3144745) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:27:59 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.6451099
[5/7/2018 4:28:11 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:28:12 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:28:12 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[5/7/2018 4:28:12 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:12.9601734) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:29:59 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:30:59 PM Error] Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
[5/7/2018 4:30:59 PM Error] Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
[5/7/2018 4:30:59 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:01:00.2319577) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:34:34 PM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test discovery starting...
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Informational] Test discovery completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3801077
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:34:36 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.89196) ==========
[5/7/2018 4:34:41 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/7/2018 4:34:42 PM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Informational] Found 0 tests in executable C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Informational] Running 0 tests...
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.3975222
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\ruggiero\source\repos\Google Test - Sandbox\Debug\Google Test - Sandbox.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[5/7/2018 4:34:43 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.9803681) ==========
```

It doesn't seem to be discovering either of the tests I'd written, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It seems you should add `RUN_ALL_TESTS` into your `main`. See the example https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md

Comment: You should not include *.cpp files as in: `#include "../ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1.cpp`. Second, to be able to use gtest, you need to include it (is it included in "pch.h"?). And third, gtest has a particular way to be initialized and executed. Look at the docs

Comment: @NuPagadi This was all I needed!

Comment: @Amadeus Looks like it was just the initialization that I was missing.  Gtest is included from pch.h   Why is including #.cpp a bad practice?

Comment: @NeilRuggiero I'll not get into details, but you can look here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header By the way, why is gtest.h buried in pch.h?

Comment: @Amadeus Thanks for the link, much appreciated!  I'm not exactly sure why gtest.h is included from pch.h, that was the way the project was set up using the built in Visual Studio tool

Comment: @NeilRuggiero pch means "Precompiled Header". That file is optional. You can include gtest.h directly, delete pch.h and deactivate precompiled headers in the compiler options, i.e. in the project properties under Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Precompiled Headers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GoogleTest framework in the common case [requires](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md) `RUN_ALL_TESTS` macro in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Then you can add your tests into different `cpp` files and the magic under the hood will launch all of them and show nice report.

Although, you can use Google Tests even without this macro. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457856/whats-the-difference-between-gtest-lib-and-gtest-main-lib).

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixes my issue.  Accepting your answer.

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: I have the same issue. Where should RUN_ALL_TESTS be added? In the test.cpp or ConsoleApplication1.cpp?

Comment: @Hamid, in test.cpp. There is no main function in library, if you're going to test it.

Comment: @NuPagadi I have the same problem. However, if I add the main function in the test project it complains that main has been defined twice. This is obviuosly the case since I already have a main function in my main.cpp (part of the actual project). In that project the test framework is not included (so I don't have access to the the headers to include it there) Help please?

Comment: @AdrianKoch, it seems like you link the main project to the test project. The purpose of gmock and unit testing overall is to test separate classes. What you should do is to compile implementations of your classes (without your project entry point) and link to gmock.

Comment: @NuPagadi Ok that makes a lot of sense. So for a c style project that only contains functions and structs I would have my functions in a separate file and only include that file to the test project?

Comment: @AdrianKoch, plain C code cannot be mocked with gmock out of the box. However, there are some tricks you can do. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989040/can-gmock-be-used-for-stubbing-c-functions

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is quite old, but I found another potential cause for this error. In my case, the test exe file could not load a DLL, and terminated without providing the test listing. I changed the test unit's output directory in the project settings to be the same as the DLL, and the tests worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer about `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` in `main()` is close, yet there are details. Have currently discovery working without manual main.

Worth a note that setting **Project Configuration** -> *Referenced Packages* -> *Google test* -> *Use Google Test's main Function* is supposed to provide main automatically.

It may be useful to enable debug under *Tools* -> **Options** -> *Test Adapter for Google Test* -> *General* -> *Print Debug Info*.

After enabling, had additional entries in the log:

> ```
> Found 4 test method symbols and 0 trait symbols in binary  ...  
> Found 0 tests in executable ...  
> Test discovery completed ...  
> No test is available in ...
> ```

An actual problem was including wildcard ***\*.obj** in *Additional Dependencies* (with intention of avoiding of adding each .obj manually). This also included obj with `main()` from referenced project, which somehow replaced the intended by GT alternative.
Removing excessive ***.obj** solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@NuPagadi have right with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222276/2050745). If you after that still have problems, use right google test nuget. I have same code, I just switch from [dyn.rt-dyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn/) to [static.rt-dyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn/) and test explorer find all tests.